# Retrieving a int value from database

Tags: sql, ajax

I am trying to get sender_id and receiver_id into my variables but it is giving me following **error**

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   object given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Task/php/insertdatanew.php on line
>   36
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object
>   given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Task/php/insertdatanew.php on line 42 N

**CODE:**

```
 <?php
          $sender_id = 0;
          $receiver_id = 0;
          session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
        //header('location: chat.php');
    }
    else {
        header('location: chatlogin.php');
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['sender']) AND isset($_REQUEST['msg']) AND isset($_REQUEST['time']) AND isset($_REQUEST['receiver']) ){

        $msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];
        $time = $_REQUEST['time'];
        $sender = $_REQUEST['sender'];
        $receiver = $_REQUEST['receiver'];



        echo $sender;
        echo $receiver;
        echo $msg;
        echo $time;

    //echo $msg;

        if ( empty($_REQUEST['msg']) ) {
        }

        else{
            require_once 'dc_chat.php';
            $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

            $result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT id from users where username LIKE '{$sender}'");

            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); 
            $sender_id = $row[0]; 

            $result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT id from users where username LIKE '{$receiver}'");
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); 
            $receiver_id = $row[0]; 

            //echo $receiver_id;

            $sql = $mysqli -> query("INSERT  INTO `messages` (`sender_id`, `receiver_id`, `msg`, 'chattime') VALUES ('{$sender_id}', '{$receiver_id}', '{$msg}' ,'{$time}')");              

                if(! $sql ) {
                    echo 'N';
                }
                else {
                    echo 'Y';
                }
            }
        }


        else{
            echo "hello";
        }



?>
```

I am getting $msg, $time, $sender, $receiver from a ajax and datatype is JSON

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing mysql and mysqli functions. `mysql_fetch_row` should probably be `mysqli_fetch_row`.

Replace `if (!$sql)` with `if ($mysqli->affected_rows == 0)` to test for success on the INSERT statement.

If you suspect an error in your SQL statement use `echo $mysqli->error;` after your query line to put that on the screen.

Comment: thanks !! :) However my following query is not executing
$sql = $mysqli -> query("INSERT  INTO messagse (sender_id, receiver_id, msg, 'chattime') VALUES ({$sender_id}, {$receiver_id}, '{$msg}' ,'{$time}')");    

          if(! $sql ) {
              echo 'N';
          }
          else {
              echo 'Y';
          }

sender_id and receriver_id are integers in database

Comment: @Manx_Warrior updated my answer. However, I don't really understand what "is not executing" means.